# Value assigned in one example isn't carried into another example

Tags: ruby, rspec

In the following, I stored a value for `@variable` in `example 1`. But it is empty in `example 2`.

```
class GeographicLocationTest < Minitest::Test
  describe "geographic location" do
    it "example 1" do
      @variable = "Sample variable"
    end
    it "example 2" do
      puts "string"
      puts @variable
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone give a suggestion on where I went wrong.

Comment: What is wrong? You tell us, not the other way around.

Comment: @sawa i am unable to get value from one example to other

Comment: I am Struck on it. help me anyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instance variables are not shared between `it` examples. You can use a `before` block for that:

```
class GeographicLocationTest < Minitest::Test
  describe "geographic location" do
    before(:each) do
      @variable = "Sample variable"
    end

    it "example 1" do
      expect(@variable).to eq "Sample variable"
    end

    it "example 2" do
      expect(@variable).to eq "Sample variable"
    end
  end
end
```

Initialize in [before](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) method. It will apply to each `it` in the `describe` here.

If you want to set a different value for the instance variable in each test, you need to re-assign it there.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Use `before` hook:

```
class GeographicLocationTest < Minitest::Test
  describe "geographic location" do
    before do
      @variable = "Sample variable"
    end
    it "example 1" do
      # no need of the following line now
      @variable = "Sample variable"
    end
    it "example 2" do
      puts "string"
      puts @variable
    end
  end
end
```

More about it in the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But my problem is *got some result in example 1. I need to get the result in another example*.

Comment: It's not a right way to do it in RSpec. But use a Class variable `@@variable` instead of `@variable` to achieve it. You should refactor your code to avoid such scenario in the specs.
The class variable solution might also throw warning while you run your specs.

Comment: Instead, you can merge the two expectations in a single test if you want to use the result of first expectation in next one. That would be more foolproof approach.